# XNA Sprites Not Drawing Correctly

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, windows-phone-7

I have a problem through out my current code where certain Texture2D's are not drawing correctly over each other.

For example, at the start I have sprite font being drawn over a background image and half the text is not shown when I add the image.

```
        _sb.Draw(_background, new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 480), Color.White);
        if (isPaused)
            _sb.DrawString(_bigFont, "Resume", new Vector2(295, 200), Color.Black);
        else
        _sb.DrawString(_bigFont, "Start", new Vector2(315, 200), Color.Black);
```

The text then seems to appear if I change the value of other text on the screen.

Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you initializing the SpriteBatch?

Comment: spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

Comment: spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);

Comment: Can we have a picture?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/28vef77/5

When I update the something else on the screen the text appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are actually playing with the Depth, you should be using `SpriteSortMode.Deferred`. [MSDN Doc Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx)

If you are drawing everything at Depth 0, I'm pretty sure that XNA will pick a draw order for you. There are others discussing a similar issue here: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/72055/439545.aspx.

In 3D, this is usually called Z-fighting.